# method within model in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model in my MVC app, 'designation'. I have a method getdesig() to simply return all of the designations. I originally had this in my controller but moved to my model recently, with the aim of decluttering my controller and making it thinner. Is this model a logical place to put such a method?

```
public class designation
{
    [Key]
    public int DesignationID { get; set; }
    public string DesignationName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<user> users { get; set; }


    private ClaimContext db = new ClaimContext();
    public List<designation> getdesig()
    {

        {
            return (from c in db.designations
                    select c).ToList();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: we only use our model to define the fields we need for the view.  we put all data base calls into a service class that we call from the controller

Comment: this is actually a model, rather than a viewmodel. So what you are saying is neither of these should contain db calls

Comment: that is what I would recommend

Comment: thanks will investigate implementing a service class

Comment: our service class doesn't have anything special.  Using our setup it would just be a class where you would put all of your database calls for that page,  something similar to what you have in your model above.  But separated out so it is cleaner like you are trying to do

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application I foudn this link on repositories that looks really useful

Answer (score 1):

yes, however in more complicated scenarios where conditions exists the controller is the spot to determine "What" needs to be loaded or "how much" needs to be loaded based off the scenario/arguments.  In this very simple example it is fine as you are just dumping all the data without regard to any context.

It is a good practice to keep your ViewModels as simple and specific to the View as possible, the ViewModel's job is to simply be a common store to drive the view.  The view relies on the model to be set with the appropriate data, it is the job of the controller to determine context and what should be populated in the model.